# Can't seem to find a way to play mp3

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-api

I've been hours going around this problem and I still can't solve it. Basically I get data from a database and using google text to speech I transform it into an mp3; after that I upload it to the google cloud storage. From there I use Twilio API to play the mp3 file when making an outbound call; I know I need to have a url for this file but I am very inexperienced in this and when I create a VoiceResponse() I can't input it. I am doing this all through Python. Is it possible for me to play the mp3 in the outbound call?
Best